How can the drop in the use of the term 'mental health' in the 80s be explained?
I struggle to explain the drop in the 80s. Any ideas? The term 'health' shows a similar trend during this period.


It was a case of temporary sanity.

These days, it seems,'mental health' seems to be an actual condition, at least in the UK, e.g. 'It's sometimes tricky being with my mother because she's got [the] mental health'.

As with any data visualization, it would help to have a link to the actual search you ran, including what corpus you tried and a paired visual showing the results for "health." That would help with identifying any factors involved.

Why is this about English Language ?  It is about Statistics??  In answer to the question, possibly because due to the machinations of the UN, there was world wide reclassification and closure of mental institutes.

Judging mental health was not PC. Who's to say my mental health is unhealthy or mental? Maybe it's a chemical imbalance. Is healthy "better"? Is better better? Who determines what's healthy? Judging was later labeled ableism.

Thank you for your comments. Here is the search I ran. I was not sure if it was the right place to ask, but I saw a couple of questions related to the ngram viewer here.

@YosefBaskin, these may be reasons for not using the term, but that does not explain why there was a drop in its use at a particular time, after which the frequency picked up again. That is what the OP is asking about.

This is not an opinion based question. It may be very difficult to answer objectively, but it still not opinion based.

I think the mental component here is a red herring, since health and diet show the same trend, but not well-being or fitness. No clear synonym pops to mind. There is a possibility that this is an artifact of the materials Google is sampling, though that seems even harder to explain.

@ihecker There are a number of things that make this question hard to answer 1) NGrams is notoriously problematic (sources, dating errors, etc) and notoriously difficult to query correctly ('mental health' may match '... mental. Health...' (OK, that is not likely but you get the point) or may not mean what you think it means). And to -justify- any kind of large frequency change (even if the frequency change is in fact an actual thing) there'd have to be a huge sociological/text study over many areas (newspapers, journal articles, trend analysis) which would have to be done.

That little bump, while quite significant looking, could easily be ... just a weird little bump that means nothing. NGrams is reliable for comparing 2x changes, but smaller than that you can't be sure there's something weird going on with the data (the distribution in reality, the OCR, the dating, some weird publication quirk (an over sampled set)).

First thing should look at the frequency of other comparable terms, which you claim to have started but don't indicate here, and if possible an investigation of the methodology and source material. It may be a case of terminology change, reclassification, of subdivision, or renaming, occurring in equivalent texts. It may reflect a change in the sort of material that NGrams uses as sources. It may be an artefact, a glitch, a bug, a misdating of a chunk of relevant material. Question is severely lacking in evidence of research, which is grounds for a downvote.

You might want to look at examples of how the phrase is used before and after the drop. There may have been a transition going on.

Per @mitch's urging, here is one possible explanation. The early 80s was an era of deinstitutionalization of asylums and the shifting of their populations to halfway houses and local communities. In large part, this was a response to documentaries wrt the appalling conditions in many large institutions as well as judicial changes in the rights of the mentally challenged to incarceration. Only people who were a danger to themselves and others could be institutionalized against their will.

Thank you, that gives me a couple of hypotheses to explore, I will update my post if I find something.

@Mitch [re your first comment] The original (at least) CV reason was 'answers are very likely to be only opinion-based' if I remember correctly. Of course, one could argue that the CV reason itself mandates opinion-based usage.

If you know the history, this is easy. I can't be bothered to write up a full answer. That said, Reagan destroyed support for mental health institutions in the 1980's by getting rid of the Mental Health Systems Act. As a result, there was tons of defunding of mental health centers etc. And the non-profits suffered too. They just threw many people on the street. It was awful. [Of course, some places were horrible] but Reagan destroyed the existing system.

One possibility occurred to me. The early 80s marked a sea change in American politics with, among other things, the aggressive defunding and dismantling of social safety nets. This included deinstitutionalization and privatization of asylums, shifting of their populations to halfway houses and local communities.
In large part, this was a response to film documentary horror stories wrt the appalling conditions in many large institutions as well as judicial changes in the rights of the mentally challenged to incarceration. No one was to be hospitalized against their will -- only people who were a danger to themselves and others could be institutionalized.

Can you say something more about 'mental health' in particular?

I thought your abstract reasoning was insightful, but as an answer would be improved considerably by adding details  about the OPs specific question.

adding this as a comment seems reasonable. If you feel all the content is relevant, you can post more than one comment.
